# Не проходит relation yii

Tags: yii

Есть две таблицы mysql : Sites_access

```
    1   id  int(11)             AUTO_INCREMENT
    2   site_id int(11)         
    3   login   varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci         
    4   password    varchar(255)    utf8_general_ci     
    5   status  int(11)
```

и Sites

```
1   id  int(11)         
2   name    varchar(55) utf8_general_ci         
3   url varchar(55) utf8_general_ci
```

обе в `InnoDB`.
 Прописываю `relation` в `SitesAcessControl.php:`

```
return array(
            'siteinfo'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Sites','site_id')
        );
```

но,выдает что
`include(site_id.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.
В чем может быть проблема? (Все варанты где то не дописал, не то поставил проверил десятки раз). Спасибо

Comment: А если ниже добавить `'access'    => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Sites_access',    'site_id')` ?

Comment: то же самое)Без изменений